# On mouseover hidden Div appears but moves later div down

Tags: html, css, layer

Site is **`www.peachhomeloans.com.au`** and I have a button `"../rebate.htm"` which on mouseover shows up a hidden `"div class="pop"` with a message. 
 
`div class="pop` has uses a minus top: in order to make it correctly overlay the  photo above.
  However the text following the `div class="pop"` moves down the equivalent space that `div class="pop"` would have taken had it not been using the top: -220px leaving a large blank space and a disjointed feel as the text jumps down then up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap both the button & the pop with a div with the css property position: relative; The absolute positioning will then play within that. Or, you could apply it to the already surrounding .main div, but your measurements would be different.